# arbitrary __getattr__ fails on classes that inherit object but not on object

Tags: python, setattr

Can anyone tell why this piece of code fails:

```
object.__setattr__(object(), 'non-existing-attribute', 200)
```

But this not:

```
class K(object):
    pass

object.__setattr__(K(), 'non-existing-attribute', 200)
```

Comment: obviously I meant object.__setattr__(object(), 'non-existing-attribute', 200)

Comment: You can edit your question.